# Can I get rid of this class member in this template?

Tags: c++, class, templates, lambda, c++17

I had a templated class that had a getter function and a setter function pointer. When I created an object of this class and I didn't want its setter to do anything I'd just pass `nullptr` as the setter function argument. Then at runtime, it would check if its setter pointer was `nullptr` to see whether it should call the setter.

Using a function pointer isn't good enough now because I want the class to be able to store a lambda. So instead of a function pointer the setter is now a template type argument. Before I used to pass a nullptr to signify that there was no setter, but now I can't, so I use a dummy char member, as you can see:

```
template <typename GetFunctionType, typename SetFunctionType = char>
class MyClass
{
public:
   MyClass(GetFunctionType getFunction, SetFunctionType setFunction = char(0)) 
      : getFunction(getFunction), setFunction(setFunction)
   {}
   GetFunctionType getFunction;
   SetFunctionType setFunction;
   typedef decltype(getFunction()) ReturnType;

   void set(ReturnType value)
   {
      if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<decltype(setFunction), ReturnType>)
      {
         setFunction(value);
         std::cout << "Setter called\n";
      }
      else
      {
         // ELSE DO NOTHING
         std::cout << "Object has no setter\n";
      }
   }
};

int main()
{
   MyClass foo([]() { return 7; }, [](int val) { std::cout << "You have set the value\n"; });

   MyClass foo2([]() {return 7; }); // THIS OBJECT HAS NO SETTER, BUT HAS A CHAR 
                                    // MEMBER THAT I USED AS A DUMMY
   foo.set(1);
   foo2.set(1);
}
```

My question is do I need that dummy char in cases where the object has no setter function?

Comment: How about using std::function as a replacement for function pointers? In that case you can check with nullptr as before.

Comment: Through [partial specialization](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/506d54bde72cebe5) ?

Comment: Broken Design? If you have a template and can prepare it with or without something, you should not deal with runtime checks. If the template should ot use a getter or setter, simply create an instance without it. Typically you can combine several classes and inherit each of them and use CRTP from the template side. Template and run time check sounds totally wrong to me.

Comment: @Klaus It's a template because the setter can be any one of many types of callables. I do the check for the setter because it may not have a setter (or need it). Whether the check is done at runtime or compile-time isn't important to me, but I don't know how to do it at compile-time (without rewriting the entire class with a different set of members), other than to use the dummy char so that I can check if the SetterType is callable through a constexpr. Do you mean by your comment that it'd be a good idea to have another class called MyClassWithSetter, inherit from MyClass...

Comment: add the setter to MyClassWithSetter and do a virtual call into set(), or something?

Answer (score 2):

> Using a function pointer isn't good enough now because I want the
>   class to be able to store a lambda!

Not completely true!

You could store the capture-less lambdas to the typed-function pointers.

See [[expr.prim.lambda.closure]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.closure#def:closure_type) *<sub>(sec 7)</sub>*

> *The closure type for a non-generic lambda-expression with **no
>   lambda-capture** whose constraints (if any) **are satisfied has a
>   conversion function to pointer to function** with C++ language linkage
>   having the same parameter and return types as the closure type's
>   function call operator.*

In addition to that, normally a getter would have a signature

```
ReturnType /*const-ref*/ <function>();
```

similarly, the setter would have

```
void <function>(ArgumentType) /*const*/; // where ReturnType  == ArgumentType usually
```

Combining these two information, I am suggesting the following re-structuring of your class.

**([See live demo online](https://godbolt.org/z/gkmbaX))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename ArgType>
class MyClass final
{
   // alias types
   using GetFunctionType = ArgType(*)(void);
   using SetFunctionType = void(*)(ArgType);

   GetFunctionType getFunction;
   SetFunctionType setFunction;
public:
   // Now you can set the function pointer to by default `nullptr`
   MyClass(GetFunctionType getFunction = nullptr, SetFunctionType setFunction = nullptr)
      : getFunction{getFunction}
      , setFunction{setFunction}
   {}

   void set(ArgType value) const noexcept
   {
      if (getFunction && setFunction)  // runtime nullptr check
      {
         setFunction(value);
         std::cout << "Setter called\n\n\n";
      } else {
         std::cout << "Object has no setter\n\n";
      }
   }
};

int main()
{
   // mention the argument type
   MyClass<int> foo(
      []() { return 7; },
      [](int val) { std::cout << "You have set the value: " << val << "\n"; }
   );

   MyClass<std::string> foo2([]() {return std::string{}; }); // also works

   foo.set(1);
   foo2.set("String");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant a capturing lambda. If it's a capturing lambda I'm pretty sure that I need to have a templated member in the class. I was just wondering if the dummy char has to be there without rewriting the entire class as a specialization for when it doesn't have a setter.

Comment: It would be good if there was a way you could pass void or 'something' so that when you declare a class member like this: T setFunction; the compiler just removes it from the class. The only ways I figured out not to use the setter is to make the type non-invocable so the compiler can do a compile-time check and not call it.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be good if there was a way you could pass `void` or '`something`'
> so that when you declare a class member like this: `T setFunction`; the
> compiler just removes it from the class.

To my understanding, when you do the *[partial specialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization)*, you do not even need to declare the `setFunction`at all.

Following is the example code, in which the first specialization

```
template <typename Getter, typename Setter>
class MyClass final{};
```

handles the when you provide `Getter` and `Setter` cases, whereas the second one handles the *no setter* situation.

```
template <typename Getter>
class MyClass<Getter, std::nullptr_t> final
```

Unfortunately, you still need to specify the second argument (i.e. `std::nullptr_t{}`) in order to choose the correct specialization.

**([See live demo online](https://godbolt.org/z/rxgG_8))**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>  // std::nullptr_t

template <typename Getter, typename Setter>
class MyClass final
{
   Getter mGetFunction;
   Setter mSetFunction;
   using ReType = decltype(mGetFunction());
   static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(mGetFunction)>, " Getter is not callable!");
   static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(mSetFunction), ReType>, " Setter is not callable!");

public:
   MyClass(Getter mGetFunction, Setter mSetFunction) noexcept
      : mGetFunction{ mGetFunction }
      , mSetFunction{ mSetFunction }
   {}
   void set(ReType value) const noexcept {
      mSetFunction(value);
      std::cout << "Setter called\n";
   }

};

template <typename Getter>
class MyClass<Getter, std::nullptr_t> final
{
   Getter mGetFunction;
   using ReType = decltype(mGetFunction());
   static_assert(std::is_invocable_v<decltype(mGetFunction)>, " Getter is not callable!");

public:
   MyClass(Getter mGetFunction, std::nullptr_t) noexcept
      : mGetFunction{ mGetFunction }
   {}

   void set(ReType value) const noexcept {
      std::cout << "Object has no setter\n";
   }
};

int main()
{
   MyClass foo{
      []() { return 7; },
      [](int val) { std::cout << "You have set the value\n"; }
   };
   foo.set(1);

   //unfortunately, needed to pass second argument for class instantiation
   MyClass foo2([]() {return 7; }, std::nullptr_t{});
   foo2.set(1);
}
```